# using web reference throws content type error

Tags: c#, web-services, webservice-client, wcf-client, web-reference

In my application, I was supposed to use a WSDL service

I have added this as web reference in VS2010 using advanced option under Add Service Reference. The functions under this service is accessible. But when I run the application it throws error as below:

```
Client found response content type of 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<soap.xml@xfire.codehaus.org>"; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="----=_Part_142_5972.13983051"', but expected 'text/xml'.
```

I have tried changing Binding settings in Web.config file as

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I have tried with both "Text" and "MTom" for MessageEncoding but returns same error.

Please let me know how this error can be handled.

Thanks in Advance...